Constant Q transform where you keep the window size constant (so Q is no longer constant)?
I've been working on implementing a constant Q transform to try and detect musical notes within an audio signal and I came across an issue. When trying to detect low frequencies the constant Q transform requires a very large window size. See my other question here: How can I use a constant Q transform to detect low frequencies without making the buffer size too large?
This leads me to another question... What if I just set the window size fixed across the whole transform, but still keep the rest of the algorithm the same? I would still end up with logarithmically spaced frequency bins that line up with musical notes, but obviously this would result in higher frequency resolution for high frequencies and lower resolution for low frequencies similar to a regular DFT.
Here is an example of this concept implemented in C++: https://godbolt.org/z/zsfaWbExx
I have two questions regarding this:

Is there anything inherently wrong with trying this? Logically it seems like it would still give me "correct" results but with lower resolution for low frequencies and higher resolution for high frequencies. As far as I can tell the results would still be "accurate". By accurate I mean it shouldn't change the results drastically to the point where it would tell me completely incorrect frequencies exist in the signal.

Is there a name for such a transform? Since Q is no longer constant it obviously could not be called a "constant Q transform" and since the bins are laid out aligned to musical notes in equal temperament it isn't exactly a DFT either. What would this transform be called?



This is equivalent to just doing a single DFT, and then interpolating the spectrum to get fractional bin indices for arbitrary frequencies.
You don't get any extra information compared to a standard DFT, so it would share the same disadvantages: the main lobe from the windowing is wide enough to make low-frequency analysis inaccurate.
Additionally, for higher frequencies you could end up measuring fewer frequencies than there are bins.  Your higher bands end up narrower than 1/3 semitones (or whatever your spacing is) which might affect the accuracy of your results as well.
